# scroll elastic search, call an API and store in elastic search asynchronous

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, asynchronous, httprequest

I have a elastic search index (30GB, 1M entries), I have to update each document with calling an API (1s execution) and do some calculus on result.

I try many things like send request with aiohttp, create a Queue with asyncio, ect

The only things who work is that:

```
def search_and_store():
    for i in range(1, count, CPU):
        hits = es.search(index=['index'], size=CPU, from_=i)['hits']['hits']
        data = [{"title": hit['_source']['name'], "body": hit['_source']['cleanText'],"id": hit["_id"]} for hit in
                hits]
        print(i)
        with Pool(CPU) as p:
            results = p.map(getresult_store, data)
            p.close()
            p.join()

def getresult_store(item):
    body = ScoreManager.get_article_score(item['title'], item['body'])
    elasticsearchManager.update_record(es, "searchdata", body, item['id'])
```

But I sure that there is a best way to do this

Comment: how about to use `logstash`. you can configure `input` and `output` plugin for `elasticsearch` and `http` `filter` plugin for calling api in `logstash`. You can try it out this as logstash can work in multi thread so might be fast.

Comment: I can't add plugging on es...

Comment: This is not plugin, it is seperate component of `elk` (Elastic, logstash and Kibana ) stack. You need to install `logstash` and setup pipeline. You can configured pipeline with 3 plugin, one input (so in your case elasticsearch), second is filter (so in your case API) and third is output (so in your case elasticsearch)